# Parental control for kid's tablet

Tags: parental-control

I have just bought a samsung galaxy tablet 2 (7.0) for my 6 year old son. He loves it but I am extremely worried that he may inadvertently access the wrong websites.

The tablet is a wi-fi version and I can switch off the internet connection but many educational games recommended by his school require a wi-fi connection.

**What are some key things that I can do to ensure adequate parental control when he is using the tablet?**

The android version is 4.0.1. I am unsure if this can be upgraded but when I run the software update, it says that the tablet has the latest version.

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts! Please note that recommendations like *Is there an app for X* are off-topic here (see the [FAQ](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for details). You might wish to consult [Where can I ask questions that aren't Android Enthusiast questions?](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/q/371/16575) to find a fitting place for your question. Also helpful: [Search for "parental"](http://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=parental) on our site.

Comment: Both of the questions as solid, requesting worthy recommendations. However, this doesn't conform to the FAQ. Also, the questions are distinctly different from one another and are best separated into distinct posts.

Comment: You forgot the title :) I've fixed that flaw and nominated your question for re-opening.

Answer (score 2):

Android 4.3 which has been just announced comes with [Multi-User With Restricted Profiles](http://www.androidpolice.com/2013/07/24/android-4-3-feature-focus-multi-user-with-restricted-profiles/) feature which

> allows the tablet owner to have granular control over the other user
>   accounts on the device.

and

> You can also control other aspects of the device: mature content filtering, access to games and user-generated content, and even specific applications